# Concatenating tuples for sql strings in python

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7

```
cur = conn.cursor()

x = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 2, 'b' : 3}]

args_str = ""
for items in x:
    a = items['a']
    b = items['b']
    args_str += ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s, %s)", (a, b)))

print args_str
```

This gives the output as :

```
(,1,,, ,2,)(,2,,, ,3,)
```

I want it as (1, 2), (2, 3)

Comment: Stop building up sql strings yourself. Seriously, it's a waste of your time (because there are libraries), and it will expose you to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Marcin What do u recommend?

Comment: Literally any sql library at all. SQLAlchemy is very popular and includes an ORM.